# mysqldump not working - error 1300 invalid utf8 character string

Tags: mysql

I have a serious problem regarding mysqldumps!

When I try to mysqldump my databases MySQL keeps telling me

> "GOT ERROR 1300: INVALID UTF8 CHARACTER STRING".

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This is while you are creating the back up, not while trying to reload it -- correct?  Please provide the outputs of `shell> mysqldump -V` and `mysql> SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: @Michael: Correct! The Version-commands you mentioned return  "mysqldump Ver 10.16 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD)" and "10.1.9-MariaDB". Please Help!

Comment: I don't have a straightforward answer... not yet, anyway.  "Got error" *should* mean the server sent that error code, though it's unclear why data already stored in a table would have bad utf8 in it or why the server is complaining when it's reading data.  Two suggestions, use `--verbose` to try to figure out what'a going on at the moment the error hits, and, if you are using redirection, like `> dumpfile`, verify that the behavior is the same if you switch to `-r dumpfile` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try with additing below options:

```
-f, --force         Continue even if we get an sql-error.
```

i.e: `mysqldump -u root -p database --force > dump.sql`

For more options, use: `man mysqldump`